# Android - hide Facebook login button

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login

I followed [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.1) to create a simple app with a login button.

Now, I wish to hide the login button after the user has already logged in.

I read here on stackoverflow that I should save the access token string and it's expiry date, and check if it's 'expired' (ignoring the case it can be expired at any time by facebook - just theoreticaly) or if it wasn't inserted yet (points that user hasn't logged in), and then show/hide the button respectively.

I tried adjusting the following method:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
    if(!hasToShowLogin()){
        authButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    return view;
}
```

the code in the method 'hasToShowButton' is not relevant because it works, it's just for the demo.

The code above should hide button when the view is first created, and this one should hide the button after the login accomplished, and located in OnActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    View view = getView();
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

What happens is that the button keep showing no matter what, and is working as usual.

So to conclude, what I'm trying to do is:

1. Hide login button after successful login
2. Hide login button in the following times the user enters the app

(In other words: never show login button when user is logged in)

Been breaking my head over this for HOURS. thanks for the helpers!

P.S Just noticed that although setVisibility doesn't hide the button, the button doesn't work after the login. So it's halfway there, I just need to hide it from screen too...

Comment: Same issue for me. When users first login; my facebook login fragment perfectly works. Than user clicks the facebook login button,this fragment disappears but "login button" changes to "logout" and still visible over my activity. I could not solve that issue. Upvote.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
boolean loggedIn = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null;
    if (loggedIn){
        loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```